# How to use delayed initialization in rust code and pass compiler "possibly-uninitialized variable" rule?

Tags: rust, initialization, delay, borrow-checker

The following rust code is a simplified version, my code needs to use delayed initialization, I want to know how to eliminate the error.

```
fn main() {
    let header: Vec<char>;
    let index = 0;
    if index == 0 {
        header = "abc".chars().collect();
        println!("{:?}", header);
    }
    println!("{}", header.len());
}
```

> quote
> error[E0381]: borrow of possibly-uninitialized variable: `header`

--> src/main.rs:8:22

```
  |
8 |     println!("{:?}", header.len());
  |                      ^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `header`
```

I know there are two solutions to get rid of the error, including:

1. let header: Vec = vec![];
2. add else block with header = ..;

But they are all not the desired way!

Comment: If you *know* that `index` must be `0`, why have the `if` at all?  If you don't know, then what should happen if it's not `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more common pattern is to use `Option` and later call `unwrap()`, but if it really must be allocated then later written, this is what [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#method.assume_init) is for. You create some uninitialized memory, then initialize it, then tell the compiler it has been initialized. The API is analogous to `Option`, except that you would fill with data rather than reassigning or replacing.

```
let mut header = std::mem::MaybeUninit::<Vec<char>>::uninit();
let index = 0;
if index == 0 {
    unsafe {
        header.as_mut_ptr().write("abc".chars().collect());
    }
    println!("{:?}", header);
}
let header = unsafe { std::mem::MaybeUninit::assume_init(header) };
println!("{}", header.len());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and the std::mem::MaybeUninit can certainly pass the compiler, but the two unsafe block are also not the ideal solution.

Comment: @user1645377 Based on your "solutions to get rid of the error", I think the safe solution you want is `Option`. Initialize to `None`, then set the value with `option.replace(value)`. No unsafe, no double allocations.

Answer (score 2):

I give the answer from @piojo:

```
fn main() {
    let mut header: Option<Vec<char>> =  None;
    let index = 0;
    if index == 0 {
        header.replace( "abc".chars().collect()  ) ;
        println!("{:?}", header.unwrap());
    }else{
        println!("{}", header.unwrap().len());
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, you can't call `unwrap()` on `None` in the `else` block if you don't want it to panic.

Comment: …and if you are happy to panic in that case (for instance, because you know it can never actually happen), you could just have put an explicit panic in the `else` block to begin with e.g. `else { unreachable!() }`.  But then one wonders (as mentioned in my comment on the question) what was the point of the `if` in the first place: perhaps an `assert_eq!(index, 0);` would have sufficed instead.